# Setting name for composer template using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

This scripts works fine for me, but every time its called, a new composer-template is created (Composer 1, Composer2 etc).
If the user saves the project, also the composers are saved and the list grows up...

So I want to remove the new item OR name it, so only one of them is in the list:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis import gui

scale = 10000
templateFile='c:/1temp/mylayout.qpt'
activetool = 15# 'MoveItemContent'

composerview = iface.createNewComposer()
#load template
f= file(templateFile, 'r')
templateContent = f.read()
f.close()
doc=QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(templateContent)
composerview.composition().loadFromTemplate(doc)
#show composer
composerview.show()
#setup map
map = composerview.composition().getComposerMapById(0)#QgsComposerMap
#extent
map.zoomToExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
#scale
if scale >0:
    map.setNewScale(int(scale))
#set activetool
if activetool is not None and activetool<>'':
    composerview.setCurrentTool(gui.QgsComposerView.Tool(activetool))
#finally
composerview.composition().refreshItems()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem for myself like this:

`def getComposerByName(self, composerName):
    composers = self.iface.activeComposers()
    for composer in composers:
        if composer.composerWindow().windowTitle() == composerName:
            return composer`

`...
composer = getComposerByName(self, 'myComposer')
if  composer is None:
    composer = self.iface.createNewComposer('myComposer')
composer.composerWindow().show()
...`

Comment: Thx a lot :) I had something similar, but your post pushed me to the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

It basically breaks down to setting `windowTitle` of the element, what is a property inherited from QWidget. Methods are `setWindowTitle` and `windowTitle` as described in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop). More complete example below:

```
# Get composer file contents
path = '' # path to .qpt file
with open(path, 'rt') as f:
    content = f.read()

# Load the content into new Composer element
myDocument = QDomDocument()
myDocument.setContent(content)
newComposition = self.iface.createNewComposer()
newComposition.composerWindow().setWindowTitle('My composition') # <-- set the name here
newComposition.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

# Access available compositions
composers = self.iface.activeComposers()
for item in composers:
    if item.composerWindow().windowTitle() == 'My composition':
        doSomething(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried something similar before. The window title has nothing to do with the name of the composer template, so it changes nothing:  every time you run it, a new item in the composer manger is created with its default name.